# How to reposition widgets in tkinter without disturbing adjacent widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a button in column 5, and have several Labels at column 1, 2, 3 and 4 (each at row 0). When I use pady for my button in column 5 , other labels also come down making it harder to achieve the desired layout.

I don't know of any other way of repositioning widgets in the y-direction except pady.

Code

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")
root.title("Stock Manager")
root.resizable(False, False)


Label(root, text="Image", font=20).grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=50)

Label(root, text="Product No.", font=20).grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)
prodnumempty = Label(root, text="00547", font=16).grid(column=1, row=1)
Label(root, text="Description", font=20).grid(column=2, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)
Label(root, text="Quantity", font=20).grid(column=3, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)
Label(root, text="Price", font=20).grid(column=4, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)

historybtn = ttk.Button(root, text="See Product History").grid(column=5, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I want the `See Product History` button to be at the bottom while other labels should remain fixed at their position.

Comment: You need to be more specific - what do you mean by come down? What is your expected output?

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are wanting. ***button should come down*** is not clear enough for us to understand your need. Please provide more context to your question.

Comment: Down in the sense that I need padding to change my button's position. It can be either in the x-direction or y-direction. So what I want is that the button should come down by increasing the y-padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have all the labels in a frame, gridded on the left, and the button gridded on th eright, in a lower row:

Something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")
root.title("Stock Manager")
root.resizable(False, False)

left_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=900, height=500)
tk.Label(left_frame, text="Image", font=20).grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=50)

tk.Label(left_frame, text="Product No.", font=20).grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)
prodnumempty = tk.Label(left_frame, text="00547", font=16).grid(column=1, row=1)
tk.Label(left_frame, text="Description", font=20).grid(column=2, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)
tk.Label(left_frame, text="Quantity", font=20).grid(column=3, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)
tk.Label(left_frame, text="Price", font=20).grid(column=4, row=0, pady=5, padx=40)

left_frame.grid(column=2, row=0)

historybtn = ttk.Button(root, text="See Product History").grid(column=5, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!